# If I change nodeSelector, will Kubernetes trigger a new deployment?

Tags: kubernetes

If I change `nodeSelector`, will Kubernetes trigger a new deployment?

I have a set of pods deployed on a node. If I change the node, the deployment will be done automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, see [Updating a deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment).

> Note: A Deployment's rollout is triggered if and only if the
> Deployment's Pod template (that is, .spec.template) is changed, for
> example if the labels or container images of the template are updated.
> Other updates, such as scaling the Deployment, do not trigger a
> rollout.